# What does "#" signify in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I come from a SQL Server background and thought that it might mean it was a temporary table, but after reading up on MySql temp tables I don't think that's true.

I'm seeing it in the following context:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM #_SomeName
```

**UPDATE**

This query is defined in a PHP string and then run against the MySQL Database.  I'm not sure if that would make a difference or not...

here is the PHP code i'm running:

```
$query="select id, name from #__SomeName";
$db=&JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from? I'm not sure what `JFactory` is, but could it be that the `setQuery` method actually modifies the query before sending it to MySQL?

Comment: It's a project that I'm helping a friend with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL `#` is an end-of-line comment:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

In JFactory, `#__` is used as a place holder.  See here:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script

Comment: Ahh thanks, sorry for the confusion.  As you can tell i'm not that familiar with joomla, php, mysql etc.

Answer (score 2):

A Comment

```
# comment
-- also a comment
```

The syntax highlighting answers the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

are you sure the table name is not quoted using backticks?  maybe in the issuing application? it might show up in MySQL's query log bare.

```
mysql> create table `#t` (i int);
mysql> insert into `#t` (i) values (10);
mysql> select * from `#t`;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|   10 | 
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a comment character. Are there more lines to your script? Basically, I'd expect something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, whatever FROM #_table
my_table WHERE id = 7;
```

Maybe someone commented out the old table name and put a new one in?

Comment: Hmm very strange.  No there are no more lines.  So this is actually a string defined in a PHP page that is then run against a MySQL DB, could that make a difference?